# ¿Alguien sabe para que uso ese return this?

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable, this

```
this.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
this.setText((String) value);
this.setBackground((isSelected)?colorBackground:Color.WHITE);
this.setFont(normally);
return this;
```

Hola, tengo un problema, no comprendo muy buen como actúa ese **this** en un método, he visto ejemplos bastantes buenos, pero muchos no hablan sobre la palabra **this**.
Alguien me explica para que sirve ese **this**, que retorna??
"todo el código esta dentro de un método", y estoy elaborando un JTable.

O talvez alguna fuente donde encontrar mas sobre el tema...porfavor

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: gracias, sobre los constructores si lo tengo claro, el único problema es saber para que sirve el return this :c, no sé como relacionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta haciendo referencia a la clase. al retornar "this" al final del seteo de los demas metodos, esta retornando la clase con sus atributos modificados.

Answer (score 0):

El "this" según lo que entiendo es para referirse al ultimo objeto creado. Te muestro el siguiente pequeño código.

```
public class Cilindro {

private double radio;
private double altura;


public void setRadio(double radio) {
    this.radio = radio; //En este caso el this.radio se refiere al valor del objeto, mientras el radio se refiere al argumento de la función.
}
```

Bajo esa logica el "this" se esta refiriendo a las propiedades del objeto creado.